# Why does the PID change when "ssh -f -N hostname" is called using subprocess in Python, and how can I terminate it reliably when my program ends?

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, pid

I need to connect to a target device over a proxy to execute some comands on the target. To do this, I need to open an SSH tunnel to the proxy, and then use a Python library to interact with the target over SSH. The library is not capable of accommodating proxied connections. This concept works when I use my shell directly to bring up the tunnel and then use the Python library to interact with the target. I now need to move the shell command into my Python program.

I tried opening an SSH tunnel using subprocess with the following code:

```python
    config_file = "path/to/config"
    cmd = shlex.split(f"ssh -f -N jumphost-tunnel -F {config_file}")
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd, stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
```

This creates two problems.

### Problem 1

When I call `process.pid` the PID is different from what I see when I execute `ps aux | grep ssh` and note the PID on the OS. It is off by 1 (i.e: PID from `subprocess.pid` is `44196` PID from `ps aux` is `44197`).

I would like to understand why the PID is off by 1. Is it due to the SSH process being placed in the background when called with `ssh -f`?

### Problem 2

It leaves a zombie SSH tunnel behind, as I cannot terminate the tunnel with `subprocess.kill()` due to not knowing the PID of the tunnel command.

How can I safely, and reliably terminate the SSH tunnel when the program completes?
For some background, I need to tunnel to a proxy server and execute a command on a target device over SSH. The target device is a Juniper SRX. I'm using the PyEZ-junos library to interact with it. The library uses Paramiko under the hood to interact with the Junos device, but the library implementation does not make use of the `ProxyCommand` or `ProxyJump` directives made available by OpenSSH, hence the call to subprocess to initiate the tunnel to the proxy server. I don't want to change the internals of the PyEZ library to fix the tunneling issue.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked, but it would surprise me if the off-by-one PID is not caused by ssh “backgrounding” itself by forking a new process and letting the original process exit.

I don't think you really need the -f flag. subprocess.Popen starts a new process anyway.

Comment: Would it be possible to use `PID +1` as the PID used to kill the process reliably across platforms? That would help me clean up the zombie SSH process it leaves when the process ends. However, it feels there should be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: +1 is not reliable as there might be other processes being created at the same time, causing the pid counter to tick up. However, as I said, why do you have the -f flag there? It should be possible to do without it, possibly with some adjustments to the Popen() parameters. That way, you could kill the process with process.kill(). (Hm, actually, I see now that I didn't say that; I wrote "-n" by mistake. Sorry about the confusion!)

Comment: The subprocess call blocks without the option to send SSH it into the background. I need it to open up the tunnel to the proxy server and then interact with the target devices.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Are you setting up an ssh tunnel, i.e. doing the equivalent of using the -L or -R command line flags? In that case, why don't you set the stdin/out/err of ssh to subprocess.DEVNULL? Or are you passing data via ssh's stdin? In that case, why are you using -n -N?

Comment: I set up a tunnel with the ssh command wrapped by subprocess to a proxy server. I then interact with a target device through the tunnel using local port forwarding over the tunnel.

I use "ssh -f -N jumphost-tunnel " so that the process goes to the background (the -f flag) and it doesn't execute any remote commands (the -N flag). stdin should be set to None by default with subprocess is my understanding.

I'm curious to know what setting stdout and stdin to DEVNULL would achieve. Could you explain please? I will test in the meantime to see how that helps too.

Comment: Setting stdout and stderr to DEVNULL when calling the command did not help unfortunately.

Comment: With stdin set to None, the child process will inherit the stdin of your Python process, which might cause it to block waiting for input. Similarly, setting the output descriptors to PIPE might cause blocking if you don't make sure to read from them. I would set all three to DEVNULL, unless I actually needed the i/o. Admittedly, there should not be much i/o going on with -N -n... Anyway, you need to get rid of that -f somehow, so it it's still blocking without -f, figure out *why* it blocks and solve that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209769/discussion-between-the-stupid-engineer-and-ture-palsson).